# Java: Drawing a Star and Connecting Points w/Drawing Panel

Tags: java, loops, drawing, polygon

I am having issues figuring out three things. (Created using Drawing Panel: http://www.buildingjavaprograms.com/DrawingPanel.java)

Problem #1: Drawing the polygon so it's centered and not crooked. It's unnoticeable with more points drawn.

Problem #2: Connecting all points of the star together so it's a giant circle (dotted). I don't see why it's happening unless maybe the method is not the best.

Problem #3: When drawn with low amounts of points, I notice that it doesn't draw a point correctly, and it looks like a square.

I'd really appreciate the help!

```
import java.awt.*;

public class StarSampler {

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(500, 500);
           Graphics2D g = panel.getGraphics();
           g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

           fillStar(g, 250, 250, 150, 5, 1);
       }

       public static void fillStar(Graphics2D g, int ctrX, int ctrY, int radius, int nPoints, double spikiness)
       {
           double xDouble[] = new double[2*nPoints];
           double yDouble[] = new double[2*nPoints];
           int xPoint[] = new int[100]; 
           int yPoint[] = new int[100];

           for (int i = 0; i < 2*nPoints; i++)
           {
             double iRadius = (i % 2 == 0) ? radius : (radius * spikiness);
             double angle = (i * 720.0) / (2*nPoints);

             xDouble[i] = ctrX + iRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
             yDouble[i] = ctrY + iRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));

           for (int j = 0; j < nPoints; j++) // Casts for ints and doubles
           {
               xPoint[j] = (int) xDouble[j];
               yPoint[j] = (int) yDouble[j];
           }
           }

           g.fillPolygon(xPoint, yPoint, nPoints); // Creates polygon
           // Polygon gets drawn crookedly
           g.drawPolyline(xPoint, yPoint, nPoints); // Draws lines to connect points
           // Two lines go straight to (0,0) when nPonts*2 and nothing without *2?
       }
}
```

My Output:

[image: Wrong Output]

My Target Output (Without labeled points, two stars just for example):

[image: Correct Output]

Answer (score 3):

The issues with your code are of logical nature or due to a sloppy coding style:

```
for (int j = 0; j < nPoints; j++) // Casts for ints and doubles
       {
           xPoint[j] = (int) xDouble[j];
           yPoint[j] = (int) yDouble[j];
       }
```

This piece of code is supposed to transform all portions of the polygon into integers. There are several issues with this piece of code:

1. It doesn't cover all points. The loop produces a total of `2 * nPoints` points, but only half of them is converted. This is where the missing spikes come from
2. Why do this in a inner loop? This shouldn't be done in the loop that generates the values. It's just an enormous number of redundant copies and casts.
3. Why keep two separate arrays at all? Just convert them directly on creation. Since no value will be reused, there's no point in keeping a value with full precision anyways.

A circle is 360 degrees, not 720. This code:

```
double angle = (i * 720.0) / (2*nPoints);
```

Will alter the angle between created points. This means you either only generate half of the spikes, if the number is even, or generate a lot of crossing lines (doesn't look bad either, but not what you want, I guess).

The unit-circle (relevant for the trignometry-part) is defined in a way such that (1, 0) is the point with an angle of 0° to the center. This is also where your first spike will be created. Simply substract 90° of the angle to rotate the circle by 90° counter-clockwise.

Here's working solution based on your code. The main-method only holds the code to manage a simple testing-UI:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class StarSampler
{
    private static final int WIDTH = 500,
                                HEIGHT = 500,
                                RADIUS = 200;

    private static final double SPIKINESS = 0.5;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        updateImage(5, bi);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Some Test");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //menu to update number of spikes
        JPanel sub = new JPanel();
        sub.setLayout(new BoxLayout(sub, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        sub.add(new JLabel("Spikes: "));
        JSpinner spikeSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(5, 1, 500, 1));
        spikeSpinner.addChangeListener(e -> {
            updateImage((Integer) spikeSpinner.getModel().getValue(), bi);
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->frame.repaint());
        });
        sub.add(spikeSpinner);
        frame.add(sub, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void updateImage(int nSpikes, BufferedImage bi)
    {
        int ctrX = WIDTH / 2, ctrY = HEIGHT / 2;

        int nPoints = nSpikes * 2 + 1;

        int xPoint[] = new int[nPoints];
        int yPoint[] = new int[nPoints];

        //generate star
        for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; i++)
        {
            double iRadius = (i % 2 == 0) ? RADIUS : (RADIUS * SPIKINESS);
            double angle = (i * 360.0) / (2*nSpikes);

            xPoint[i] = (int) (ctrX + iRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle - 90)));
            yPoint[i] = (int) (ctrY + iRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle - 90)));
        }

        //paint the star
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) bi.getGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4.f));
        g2.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g2.drawPolyline(xPoint, yPoint, nPoints);

        //insert control lines
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.f));
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        for(int i = 0; i < nSpikes * 2; i++)
            g2.drawLine(ctrX, ctrY, xPoint[i], yPoint[i]);

        int w1 = RADIUS,
                w2 = (int) (RADIUS * SPIKINESS);
        g2.drawOval(ctrX - w1, ctrY - w1, w1 * 2, w1 * 2);
        g2.drawOval(ctrX - w2, ctrY - w2, w2 * 2, w2 * 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my bad, I am using Drawing Panel (http://www.buildingjavaprograms.com/DrawingPanel.java) not JPanel. But I do really appreciate the code and I am trying to understand the logic you implemented.

Comment: @Aramza the UI-components don't exactly matter. The `updateImage`-method contains all the logic to paint the star, while the `main`-method only handles the UI and it's creation. The `BufferedImage`-Parameter of the `updateImage`-Method could easily be replaced by a `Graphics`-Object. In fact that parameter is used precisely once; to retrieve said `Graphics`-Object...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for JavaFX, I used and reworked the code above.

```
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

public class poly_star extends Group {
    public poly_star(int RADIUS, int nSpikes, double SPIKINESS, Color col){
        int ind=0;
        int nPoints = nSpikes*2+1;
        // Define an array to store the points of the polygon
        double[] points = new double[nPoints * 2];
        // Loop through each point and calculate its position
        for (int i = 0; i < nPoints ; i++) {
            double iRadius = (i % 2 == 0) ? RADIUS : (RADIUS * SPIKINESS);
            // Calculate the angle for each point
            double angle = (i * 360.0) / (2*nSpikes);
    // X point position 
            points[ind] = iRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle - 90));
    // Y point position
            points[ind+1] = iRadius* Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle - 90));
            ind +=2;
        }
        // Create a polygon object and set its points
        Polygon STARpoly = new Polygon(points);
        STARpoly.setFill(col);
        getChildren().add(STARpoly);
    }
}
```

And you can call it from from anywhere, just add parameters what you like:

```
 poly_star myStar = new poly_star(280,13,0.6,Color.YELLOW);
 myStar.setLayoutX( someXpos );
 myStar.setLayoutY( someYpos );
 getChildren().add(myStar);
```